# Winform Designer generated name bug with custom control

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

Using Visual Studio 2019, I get a  bug with a custom control, the following Numeric Up Down :

```
namespace usbACQ_ProdConf
{
    public partial class usbACQ_ProdConf : Form
    {
        public class MyNumericUpDown : NumericUpDown
        {
            protected override void UpdateEditText()
            {
                Text = ((uint)Value).ToString("X4");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Every time I edit the design, an error gets generated in the designer because it adds a parasite `.usbACQ_ProdConf` : 
What is generated :

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
        this.nUD_usbPID = new usbACQ_ProdConf.usbACQ_ProdConf.MyNumericUpDown();
```

What I have to edit every time :

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
        this.nUD_usbPID = new usbACQ_ProdConf.MyNumericUpDown();
```

Does anyone know how to fix this annoying bug ?

Comment: Move your Custom Control class outside the Form class (within its own class, as it should be) and give your Form a name that is not the same as the Namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Jimi,
I renamed the namespace and put the custom control class outside of the other class. It works now and the name is just `MyNumericUpDown`